# give names to a var object in .net

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, var

just wondering I am using a web method to return some json data to a web form. anyway I don't want the entire class in json just two of the columns.  so I used linq to get the columns here is an example.

```
 IEnumerable<Person> model = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { id = 1, Name = "Bryan", Phone = "218-0211", Email = "bryan@mail.mil" },
            new Person { id = 2, Name = "Joe", Phone = "248-0241", Email = "joe@mail.mil" },
            new Person { id = 3, Name = "Fred", Phone = "354-0441", Email = "fred@mail.mil" },
            new Person { id = 4, Name = "Mary", Phone = "344-3451", Email = "mary@mail.mil" },
            new Person { id = 5, Name = "Jill", Phone = "127-3451", Email = "jill@mail.mil" }

        };
        var mysubset = from a in model select new { a. Name, a.Email };
```

unfotunately when I then serialize my result and send it back I lose the column names.  so data.name doesn't work so I was wondering can I give names to a var type?   for example is there a way to do this?

```
var mysubset = from a in model select new { a. Name, a.Email };
        string myname as string;
        foreach (var item in mysubset)
        {
            myname = subset.Name;
        }
```

ok here is the actual code sorry it is in vb but that is the project I inherited

```
Dim mycollection = From a in cmpnyList select {a.CmpnyName, a.ShipFrom}
return jsSerialize.Serialize(mycollection)
```

the json returned from that is

```
[{"Company A","New York"},{"Company B", "Harrisburg"}]
```

so I'm trying to get back something like

```
 [{"CmpnyName":"Company A", "ShipFrom": "New York"},
    {"CmpnyName": "Company B", "ShipFrom": "Harrisburg}]
```

Comment: cool, thanks that's easy enough

Comment: ok, as soon as it lets me I'll check it

Comment: Can you post the json serialization logic for the client?

Comment: ok here is the actual code (sorry it is in vb not my fault that is the project I inherited)

Comment: Which serializer are you using?

Comment: Romoku asked which serializer I am using it is System.Web.Scipt.Services.JavaScriptSerializer but that seems to be working fine

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in C# or VB on .NET 3.5 to 4.5.1. Can you include a complete program demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73996/discussion-between-user2744722-and-romoku).

Comment: You say you use `JavaScriptSerializer` and "that seems to be working fine". That doesn't compute. Your question is about the serializer *not* working fine. BTW No serializer that I know of produces this kind of Json from anon. types, nor are they able to deserialize such a string. Something else must be going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're using json.net the answer would be something like this using jobject(newtonsoft.json.linq)

```
JObject o = new JObject(
            new JProperty("PersonssList",
            new JArray(
                from p in model
                select new JObject(
                    new JProperty("PersonName", p.Name),
                    new JProperty("Email", p.Email)))));
```

and the result would be this json

```html
  {
"PersonssList": [
    {
      "PersonName": "Bryan",
      "Email": "bryan@mail.mil"
    },
    {
      "PersonName": "Joe",
      "Email": "joe@mail.mil"
    },
    {
      "PersonName": "Fred",
      "Email": "fred@mail.mil"
    },
    {
      "PersonName": "Mary",
      "Email": "mary@mail.mil"
    },
    {
      "PersonName": "Jill",
      "Email": "jill@mail.mil"
    }
  ]
```